# Adding all state in dropdown from JSON file based on country selection

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have list of countries and their states in JSON file, below is how it looks like

```
"NO": {
"name": "Norway",
"states": {
  "VA": {
    "name": "Vest-Agder"
  },
  "RO": {
    "name": "Rogaland"
  },
  "HO": {
    "name": "Hordaland"
  },
  "SF": {
    "name": "Sogn og Fjordane"
  },
  "MR": {
    "name": "Møre og Romsdal"
  },
  "ST": {
    "name": "Sør-Trøndelag"
  },
  "NO": {
    "name": "Nord-Trøndelag"
  },
  "NT": {
    "name": "Nordland"
  },
  "TR": {
    "name": "Troms"
  },
  "FI": {
    "name": "Finnmark"
  },
  "SJ": {
    "name": "Svalbard"
  },
  "SJ": {
    "name": "Jan Mayen"
  },
  "AK": {
    "name": "Akershus"
  },
  "AA": {
    "name": "Aust-Agder"
  },
  "BU": {
    "name": "Buskerud"
  },
  "HE": {
    "name": "Hedmark"
  },
  "OP": {
    "name": "Oppland"
  },
  "OS": {
    "name": "Oslo"
  },
  "TE": {
    "name": "Telemark"
  },
  "VF": {
    "name": "Vestfold"
  },
  "OF": {
    "name": "Østfold"
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to list the state names based on country selection in dropdown menu. Let say if Norway is selected as country, the dropdown will contain all the state names in list and short name in value

I created the code below, but getting empty dropdown

```
$conobjitems = json_decode($jsonitemfile);
        echo "<select>";
$findBystatename = function($constatename) use ($conobjitems) {
        foreach($conobjitems->Norway as $short){
            echo "<option>". $short . "</option>";
        }
};
        echo "</select>";
```

Need advise here.

Comment: You're defining findBystatename as a function but never actually calling that function anywhere hence your output is likely just <select></select>

Comment: @Simon thank you, I have fixed my code it was a mistake from my end :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct code that I came up with

```
        echo "<select>";

  foreach($conobjitems->PK->states as $short => $outputstate) {
            echo "<option value=". $short . ">". $outputstate->name . "</option>";
  }
        echo "</select>";
```